# How does Myspace refresh page without stopping music playback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, myspace

I have been using the new Myspace for quite some time now, and I am really astonished on their design. It is really elegant and they have taken advantage of many HTML5 features. However there is one thing that, to me, outshines any other functionality and that is how you could navigate through myspace without having to stop the music playback. I noticed this a few days ago while listening to music, I changed the page and the music player would not reload. It would stay on its fixed position and the music would still play, even while the page was refreshing. And even if you log out, when you log back in the music player would play last song you were listening at exactly the time you left it on. 
**Now long story short, my question is: How do they achieve this? I am guessing they are saving the current track position in a cookie variable or in the local storage as it is playing, but what about the music player? How come it does not stop playing the song when navigating through myspace? Are they using any html5 feature to do this?** 
*note: I was inspecting their code because I thought they were using the jquery.load() function, but did not find any trace of that

Comment: Are you sure it is refreshing the page? With HTML5 you can in most browsers change the URL in the address bar without reloading the page. So it would look like you have gone to a different page but in reality you just change the URL and stay on the same page.

Comment: No I was just navigating through the site

Comment: And what HTML5 feature is that?

Comment: Lookup 'html5 history.pushstate'. I might be wrong but have a look anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the insight given by @putvande, this Myspace feature is achieved using the HTML5 History API to change the browser URL without refreshing the page. Combining this with JQuery $.ajax can produce the effects shown in myspace, github and facebook. "arundavid" has a great explanation on this link at [tinywall.info](http://www.tinywall.info/2012/02/22/change-browser-url-without-page-reload-refresh-with-ajax-request-using-javascript-html5-history-api-php-jquery-like-facebook-github-navigation-menu/)